# Растянуть табы по match parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablayout

Имеется вот такая активити:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Табы нужно растянуть, как если бы это был `LinearLayout` и у `FORM` с `PREVIEW` были одинаковые веса(делят ширину одинаково).

Разметка:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/suggestCoordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:clickable="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_gradient"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/suggestToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_gradient"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/suggestTabLayout"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/suggestViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PS. `app:tabGravity="center"` ставил `fill` - не помогает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему дело в app:tabMode="scrollable" - из-за такого значения табы занимают минимальную для себя ширину. Вам же надо на всё свободное место. Для этого надо сменить mode на fixed

Сделайте так:

```
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed"
```